# MOGA Pro Power gamepad not detected in Chrome

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, game-controllers

I've connected a MOGA Pro Power gamepad to my Nexus 5 phone, in mode B (HID). It works well in [Gamepad Tester](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chiarly.gamepad), but doesn't do anything in the Chrome browser (as tested via [html5gamepad.com](http://html5gamepad.com/)).

Is the Gamepad HTML5 API supported on Android? If so, any idea why it doesn't work with my controller?

Answer (score 2):

According to [HTML5test](http://html5test.com), Chrome for Android (as of v33) does not support controller input APIs. You'd likely have to wait for this to be implemented in some future version, or try to find a browser that does support it.

[image]